# Convert Coordinates using PHP

Tags: php, google-maps

i have coordinates like S 23° 25' 33.8" , W 47° 35' 58.4" and i want to convert to 
-23.426056, -47.599556.

How can i do this using PHP ?

EDIT

Sorry, the right question is:

When i put S 23° 34' 55.9" , W 47° 31' 14.2" in google maps he automatically point a green marker where i want, but if i put the same coordinate in example gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/… , it only point a marker in a street nearly, how can i put the green marker simlary to google maps in my application

Comment: When i put S 23° 34' 55.9" , W 47° 31' 14.2" in google maps he automatically point a green marker where i want, but if i put the same  coordinate in example http://gmaps-samples.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/geocoder/singlegeocode.html , it only point a marker in a street nearly, how can i put the green marker simlary to google maps in my application

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. It is important to **do your homework**. Tell us what you found and ***why*** it didn't meet your needs. This demonstrates that you've taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer. [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask).

Comment: sscanf() to extract values from the string; then a little bit of maths

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it with simple mathematics:

- arcsecond is 1⁄3,600 of a degree
- arcminute is 1/60 of a degree
- S,E negative, N,W positive

  example: S 23° 25' 33.8:
  -1 * 23+25/60+33.8/3600 = -23,426055555555555555555555555556°

Comment: i tried to do and the google maps give me an wrong location, i dont understand